# Question concerning pointers in C API of SQLite

Tags: c, database, sqlite, pointers

I am misunderstandng something likley fundamental concerning pointers in C.

In the code below, if `db_open( "name.db", dbP )` is invoked from within another function, the database is opened/created but `dbP` is not recognized afterward in `build_schema` but is `NULL`. If `db_open` is changed to not have an argument `sqlite3 *db` and references the gloabal `dbP`, then `dbP` is recognized in `build_schema` and is not `NULL`.

The objective is to have `db_open` accept any database name and sqlite db handle.

Would you please explain what I am doing wrong and misunderstanding?

Thank you.

---

I added more code as requested. The database is created successfully and `build_schema` is invoked but the sqlite prepare statement returns an error code of 21 because `dbP` is `null` in that function if print it out. However, if alter `db_open` to not have the second argument and reference `dbP` in all functions, `build_schema` succeeds, the SQL statements are processed, the database has tables in it, and printing out `dbP` shows something like `AL`.

```
// function prototype
int db_open( char [], sqlite3 *db ); 

// Global variables.
sqlite3 *dbP;  // The primary database.    

int main( void )
  {
    int rc;   
    switch( rc = db_open( "path/db_name.db", dbP ) )
       {
         case 'c' :
              build_schema( &J[ i ] );  
              break;
         case 'o' :
            get_base( &J[ i ] ); 
            break;
         default: ...;
       }
    }

int db_open( char db_name[], sqlite3 *db )
  { 
    int rc; 
    // Attempt to open the database as if already existed; will fail if does not exist. 
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2( db_name, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL );
    if ( rc == 14 )
      {
        // Error code of 14 is a generic "unable to open database." 
        // First, assume failed to open because database doesn't exist; and modify flags to attempt to create it anew. 
        rc = sqlite3_open_v2( db_name, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL );
        // If rc > 0 then failed to create a database; otherwise, return "c" indicating successful creation of database.
        return rc ? 'e' : 'c';
      } 
    else if ( rc )
      // Correction of error codes other than 14 is not attempted, and user is informed. 
      return 'e';
    else
      // Existing database opened successfully.
      return 'o';
  } // close db_open

void build_schema( char *j )
  {
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *sql;
    const char *tail;
    int rc;

    sql = "SQL statement_1 to create a table;"
          "SQL statement_2 to create a table;"
          "SQL statement_3; to create a table";

    while ( sqlite3_complete( sql ) )
      {
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2( dbP, sql, -1, &stmt, &tail );
        sqlite3_step( stmt );
        sql = tail;
      }

    sqlite3_finalize( stmt );
  }
```

Comment: I was wrong. I thought you declared dbP inside a function (first if statement). Later, I thought you declared dbP outside any function ( second if statement).

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps it has something to do with it being a sqlite3 variable type or whatever the correct term is for the database handle. Unless I'm misunderstanding my other code, the same method of passing a pointer appears to work fine for other variable types. Most likey it's not necessary because in SQLite, if another database needs to be opened, it will be attached rather than opened through `db_open`. I would like to understand the reason though.

Comment: Can you show us entire code?

Comment: I added more code that I think is enough to illustrate all the steps involved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are passing the value of `dbP` rather than the location of `dbP` to your helper function which then takes the location of its argument so when the `sqlite3_open_v2` function writes. It is writing to the location of the argument of the `db_open` function `db` rather than the location of the global `dbP`.

```
int sqlite3_open_v2(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb,         /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
  int flags,              /* Flags */
  const char *zVfs        /* Name of VFS module to use */
);
```

`db_open` should take a `sqlite3 **` and then it should just pass it along. This then puts the & in the right place. So see have a `&dbP`.

```
switch( rc = db_open( "path/db_name.db", &dbP ) )

int db_open( char db_name[], sqlite3 **db )

rc = sqlite3_open_v2( db_name, db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL );
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. I tried this last night for some time, that is, to make a pointer to a pointer. I had it right in the prototype and call to `db_open`, but made the mistake of also changing the `db` in the `sqlite3_open_v2 statement` to `&db` and couldn't get it to compile. Thanks again.